# Light replacement for a complicated light ceiling cover

Tags: ceiling, cover

I need to replace the lights in the below shown light ceiling cover. I have read another post on this forum and tried those methods I.e. sliding the glass cover between the metal holdings or trying the move one of the side brackets but it doesn't work. Any advice would be greatly appreciated. 
[image: Main light cover]

[image: All three side holders are the same]

[image: Holder from a differt angle]

Comment: Could you photograph the other two clips for us? Just one "profile shot" like your second photo above would suffice.

Answer (score 2):

Usually, ONE of those clips will be spring-loaded while the other two are fixed (as shown in the photos).

Comment: Hi, I tried moving all the clips it didn't budge. I was worried that the clip would break

Comment: Hmmmm... could you photograph the other two clips for us? Just one "profile shot" like your second photo above would suffice.

Answer (score 0):

I had a light fitting like that.  One, but only one as I recall, of the clips will pull away from the light diffuser.  When you find which one it is, pull it away and the diffuser will simply slide out from the others.